# URL rewriting in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, url-rewriting

I am Amit. i am new to Rails. Please forgive me if ask any stupid
questions.

I have gone through this article. I am also suffering with the same
problem.

my website URL like this:  locahost:3000/users/edit/30

I don't want to show the controller:users and action: edit.

I want to Re-Write (rewrite) the URL or i want to maintain the URL as
http://127.0.0.0:3000/30/ only.(30 is a user id)

I am not interested to show the controller(user) and action (edit)

I total intention is to Hiding (HIDING) and rewriting (REWRING) the URL
and mainly i want to hide the URL Extensions with controller and actions
mainly..

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd requirement to want to use a route this way as it will make it difficult for you to expand this scheme to support other actions in your application. One of the advantages of Rails conventions done as they are is that you usually don't have to worry about (often trivial) application details or have to have strong opinions about them.

But it you really, really want to, you can add this to your `config/routes.rb`

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect "/:id", :controller => "users", :action => "edit"
end
```

Remember that this limited scheme will mean you can only route to the edit action. Not terribly useful I would suggest.

Comment: i agree with @bjg. i think if you try to visit http://127.0.0.0:3000/logout it will reroute to user/edit/logout assuming logout as the id

Answer (score 1):

The rails routes.rb file is your answer:

Lots of information here on how to do exactly what you need:

http://guides.rails.info/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes

Answer (score 0):

For most application I have been using the standard:

```
/script.cgi?arg1=foo&arg2=bar
```

Now obviously /user/edit/eric looks much better for a URL that involves 
editing the "Eric" user. But how does this work out when you have 
multiple items. For example if I want to delete a group of users. I 
might have something like this in the old way:

```
/user/delete.cgi?id=3&id=5&id=7
```

or for a more readable format we could have:

```
/user/delete.cgi?username=eric&username=john&username=paul
```

This of course assumes that usernames are unique. :) So it seems that I 
would want something like:

```
/user/delete/eric/john/paul
```

This makes it obvious what is happening from the url. But how do I 
generate this? And if a action receives this request how does this get 
parsed so I have something like:

```
@delete_usernames ===>>> [ 'eric', 'john', 'paul' ]
```

This way I can then load up those users and delete them. I know that 
ActionController provides some methods for dealing with URL rewriting 
but I am unsure how to best use them. Any help or pointers are greatly 
appreciated.